# Image jump addition to javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, html

Is there a way to jump to a jpeg by turning the three images underneath div "fadein" into buttons? At the moment the three jpgs are just on a loop. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're using [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/), which offers a [`show()`](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/api/methods/#show-index) function. Use it in conjunction with an event handler, using `[click](ttp://api.jquery.com/click/)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work, but can't you add an empty link to the images and use a .click() jQuery event to switch between the images?